# subsetting rows in data.table with "wildcards"

Tags: r, parameter-passing, data.table

I have a data.table like this (only more columns and a lot larger obviously^^)

```
> DT = data.table(a=c(1,1,2,2),b=c(1,1,1,2),c=c(2,2,2,2),num=c(6,5,4,3))
> DT
   a b c num
1: 1 1 2   6
2: 1 1 2   5
3: 2 1 2   4
4: 2 2 2   3
```

I want to write a function `getContent()` that returns all num-values for given indecies (a,b,c) in descending order. E.g. `getContent(c(1,1,2))` wourld return "6 5".

However the given indecies can be NA and I want to treat them as wildcards, so `getContent(c(NA,1,2))` would return "6 5 4" and `getContent(c(2,NA,2))` would return "4 3"

I found a way to return all num-values without if/else logic:

```
getContent <- function(Indecies){
    setkeyv(DT,letters[1:3][!is.na(Indecies)])
    DT[as.list(Indecies[!is.na(Indecies)]),num]
}
```

But is there a better (i.e. faster) way? Especially without setting the key of DT? I mean `getContent(c(2,NA,2))` can be implemented as `DT[a==2 & c==2,num]`

And how do I return the list in descending order without ordering it as a post-processing step? (I'd like to use `setorderv(DT,c(letters[1:3][!is.na(Indecies)],-num))` but that doesn't work although the error says 'marked as sorted' would be enough)

So something like this would be nice:

```
getContent <- function(Indecies){
    DT[as.list(Indecies[!is.na(Indecies)]),num,
       by=.(letters[1:3][!is.na(Indecies)],-num)]
}
```

Any help or links are much appreciated! :-)

Comment: If you have to set the key inside the function (i.e., every time the function is called) it will be fairly slow. If instead you set the key to the full set of indices `setkey(DT,a,b,c)`, then you can just replace your `NA`/wildcard with `unique(b)` or whatever letter is the wildcard: `sort(DT[J(2,unique(b),2)]$num,decr=TRUE)`. (I'm not posting as an answer because I don't want to turn it into a function, but anyone else can.)

Comment: I've wrote a function which allows to perform binary search and allow to skip any chosen columns in the key. see [dwtools::idxv](https://github.com/jangorecki/dwtools/blob/master/tests/example-idxv.R). Instead `NA` you use `TRUE`. Will be faster than `unique(col)` because it keeps precalculated indices. Also it will be depracated when [data.table#1067](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1067) will be resolved. Still it doesn't solve *values in descending order* part of your question but it should speed up filtering by extending binary search.

Comment: Such `unique(col)` can be slower even than vector scan in some cases so if you go this way you should test it on your data.

Comment: @Frank : the approach is nice, but my table is HUGE doing unique() on any column will be slow! (could be done as preprocessing, but that will waste memory) and did I mention that I have a variable amount of letter-columns? and any of those could be NA in each call.. not sure how to transfer that into a function

Comment: @JanGorecki : thanks for the links - so I'm not the only one with this problem - unfortunately I can't use dwtools.. Is there a way with data.table itself?

Comment: @Andi yes, see the source of `idxv` and `CJI` functions, copy them. It doesn't require anything else. 51 lines of code including documentation.

Comment: Ah, fair point. I've never had a data.table so big that `lapply(DT,unique)` couldn't fit in memory, though. You'd just have to save that and refer to it whenever you need a wildcard column. However, another weakness of the approach I suggested is that it will only work for one wildcard column. With two, you'd have to take the cross product, which could certainly be burdensome. And another weakness: I guess my approach would yield `NA` nums for key combinations that are not observed, which is really not ideal. Jan's tool sounds really useful; I've also been waiting for this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the straightforward solution not good enough for you?

```
setorder(DT, -num)
getContent = function(idx) {
  if (all(is.na(idx))) return (DT[, num])

  cols = names(DT)[which(!is.na(idx))]
  vals = idx[!is.na(idx)]

  DT[eval(parse(text = paste(cols, vals, sep = " == ", collapse = " & "))), num]
}

getContent(c(1, NA, 2))
#[1] 6 5
```

Comment: ohhh that is a neat eval+parse+paste expression! I was playing around with a recursive function to do the same, but this is much cleaner and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Maybe fix needed if input is all NAs ;-)

Comment: @Andi fair enough, fix added